# Delphi IDE has no color control for Standard Components

Tags: delphi-ide

My Alexandria Delphi IDE has lost its color control for Standard Components.
I cannot set the Font color at design time for components like TLabel, but it's correctly applied at run time.

Non-standard components i.e. JvLabel seem to work at design time and run time.

Parent Font is False.

Have I screwed a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view this is a new bug in the Designer of Delphi 11.

In Delphi 10.4.2 the color display of TLabel.Font.Color still worked correctly in the Designer.

I recommend creating an RSP in Embarcadero's Quality Central for this bug.

**Update 19-Jan-23:**

This is an already known problem of Delphi 11.X.
You can uncheck "Tools->Options->User Interface->Form Designer->mimic the system style" option as a workaround.

Comment: I entered an Report in Embarcaderos Quality Center for this issue. Hope it can be still solved with the next version.